# Finding the flux of a cylinder using the Divergence Theorem

Tags: vector-fields, divergence-operator, parametrization

I have to calculate the flux of the
$$F(x,y,z)=(x+\ln(yz^{2}),y+e^{-(x^{2}+z^{2})},2z)$$
through the cylinder (without its bases): 
$$\frac{x^{2}}{4}+\frac{y^{2}}{9}=1$$
for $z\in[0,4]$.

I know that if $S_{1}, S_{2}$ are the cylinder bases and $S_{3}$ its "body", then let
$$S=S_{1}\cup S_{2}\cup S_{3}$$
so I can apply the divergence theorem in $S$. When I do it, I get:
$$\iint \limits_{S} F\;dS=96\pi$$
But I know that
$$\iint \limits_{S} F\;dS=\iint \limits_{S_{1}} F\;dS+\iint \limits_{S_{2}} F\;dS+\iint \limits_{S_{3}} F\;dS$$
So, to finish my exercise, I have to evaluate
$$\iint \limits_{S_{1}} F\;dS\quad\text{and}\quad\iint \limits_{S_{2}} F\;dS$$
Let $S_{1}$ be parameterized by
$$\sigma(r,\theta)=(2r\cos\theta,3r\sin\theta,4)$$
When I use this parameterization to calculate $\iint \limits_{S_{1}} F\;dS$, I get
$$\sigma_{r}\times\sigma_{\theta}=(0,0,6)$$
If I use this vector above in the formula of the flux through a surface, I get:
$$\iint \limits_{S_{1}} F\;dS=288\pi$$
My question is: my teacher used this parameterization for $S_{1}$:
$$\sigma(u,v)=(u,v,4)$$
and then he got
$$\iint \limits_{S_{1}} F\;dS=48\pi$$
So, which parameterization should I use? Could he do like that? Just take $(u,v,4)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the flux component along $z$ is equal to $0$ for $z=0$ and it is equal to $8$ for $z=4$. Thus the overal flux through the bases is

$$8\cdot A=48 \pi$$

Note that with your first parameterization we obtain the same result, that is

$$\iint \limits_{S_{1}} F\;dS=\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^1 (F_x,F_y,8)\cdot (0,0,6r)\,dr=2\pi\cdot 48\cdot[r^2/2]_0^1=48\pi$$

Comment: But shouldn't be $dS$ just $dr d\theta$?

Comment: We have $$\sigma_{r}\times\sigma_{\theta}=(0,0,6r)$$